# May my Android application imitate system Intent?

Tags: android, security

When an Android device receives a message, a broadcast intent 'android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED' is fired. The intent also includes the SMS that is sent.

Does Android have any defence against an application, which may maliciously send the intent 'android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED'?

Comment: The system transports the intents and I guess it won't forward system intents from non system applications.

Comment: It varies by broadcast. The docs will say "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system" on those known to be protected from this sort of spoofing. Or, in some cases, you wind up defending yourself with required permissions (e.g., on the `<receiver>`). As of Android 4.3, [you had to use the latter approach](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/06/secured-broadcasts-sms-clients.html). I have not checked this since the 4.4 SMS overhaul.